# Windows Forms C# - Make DataGridView push down other controls as rows are added

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a handful of different DGV's that all need to be displayed on the same tab in my form. Sometimes the forms will have nothing added to them, others will have many rows added to them.  I have tried using a TableLayoutPanel, a FlowLayoutPanel, and a regular Panel to hold all my containers/controls, and have tried various settings of "Dock: Fill; Dock: Top" and "Grow: True" but I cannot seem to find the right combination of controls and properties.

I am about to resort to trying to handle this programatically, but if I could handle exclusively in properties that would be great.

[image: Here is a snippet of what our form is doing now as we add rows to one DGV.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My resolution was to use a TableLayoutPanel, and programmatically grow each DGV as rows are added, which will force the panel that is containing the DGV to grow and push down the following cells.

My C# code for those who would *really* like to see it (haha):

```
    private void AddFeature_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        presenter.AddFeature_Click();
        presenter.GrowDataGridView(FeatureGridView);
    }
```

---

```
    public void AddFeature_Click()
    {
        if (view.BindingSource == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        AddFeatureRow((DataTable)(view.BindingSource.DataSource));

    }
```

---

```
    public void GrowDataGridView(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        dgv.Height += 22;
    }
```